# How to change multi Spinner's value

Tags: android, android-spinner

I use two Spinner and get data from asyncTask when I get first spinner and want get the 2th spinner but when setadapter ..  two spanner's data are the same...

This is i setadapter first time.

```
List<String> none=new ArrayList<String>();
        none.add("none");
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapterchoseTime = 
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, none);
        adapterchoseTime.setDropDownViewResource(
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapterchoseProm = 
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, none);
        adapterchoseProm.setDropDownViewResource(
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        choseTime.setAdapter(adapterchoseTime); 
        choseProm.setAdapter(adapterchoseProm);
```

I get Spinner 1's data

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapterchoseTime=(ArrayAdapter<String>)choseTime.getAdapter();

            adapterchoseTime.clear();
            adapterchoseTime.addAll(time);

            choseTime.refreshDrawableState();
```

and i get spinner2's data

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterchoseTime = (ArrayAdapter<String>)choseTime.getAdapter();

        adapterchoseTime.clear();
        adapterchoseTime.addAll(time);


        ArrayAdapter<String> adapterchoseProm = (ArrayAdapter<String>)choseProm.getAdapter();
        adapterchoseProm.clear();
        adapterchoseProm.addAll(prom);
        choseTime.setAdapter(adapterchoseTime); 
        choseProm.setAdapter(adapterchoseProm);
```

And then  I get two same spinner...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're referencing the same spinner from your setDropDownViewResource.

```
adapterchoseTime.setDropDownViewResource(
android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

One of these needs to reference the second spinner.

Comment: yeah its same spinner layout ...   First i gave two spinner a default  none  then download datalist like 10:00  11:00  12:00  show it in spinnerTime  then download 2th datalist like aaa bbb ccc after setAdapter ...  all of spinner are aaa bbb ccc